# Error with Opencart Exstension Installer

Tags: ftp, opencart

I am completely new to opencart and not technically experienced. I have searched for an answer everywhere I know. 
I have installed Opencart2 on my local machine and want to use the Exstension installer. 
The system uses FTP, so I created a Local FTP using Filezilla Server. No problems.
I then set the Opencart system FTP setting with the FTP credentials. The FTP root is set as localhost/mydomain
On running the extension installer I get the following error:
"SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data
OK
<**Warning**: ftp_chdir(): CWD failed. "/:/localhost/mydomain": directory not found. in **C:\xampp\htdocs\mydomain\admin\controller\extension\installer.php** on line **228**{"error":"Could not set root directory as "}"]

I have tried various combinations of the FTP root folder i.e. Localhost, , but nothing seems to get rid of the error. I would be very grateful if anyone could guide me.

Thank you

Comment: OpenCart 2.0.0.0 still has a lot of issues despite being released (many would agree prematurely). It's certainly not ready for a live store. The issue above should be reported on the github issue tracker

Comment: It doesn't sound like you've used the right root path for your FTP account. When you connect using an FTP client, what path do you need in order to get to your mydomain folder? It's probably either one of `/`, `/mydomain` or `/htdocs/mydomain`

Answer (score 5):

I know it's a old question but if anyone are having the same problem you can use the the mod made by Manoel Vidal, they will allow you to use the OC installer without FTP, just dowload and instll it with the OC installer then go to Extensions->Modifications and hit refresh and that is it, you can use OC installer now.

Download link -> https://github.com/opencartbrasil/instalador-sem-ftp/archive/master.zip

Sorry for my english...

Answer (score 2):

Well, this small VQMod file is very usefull:

https://codeload.github.com/opencartbrasil/instalador-sem-ftp/zip/master.zip

But there is an error when I was using this file in OC. 2.0.0.0. so, I modified that a little. I've changed the xml file. From:

```
 <operation>
      <search>
        <![CDATA[public function ftp() {]]>
      </search>
      <add position="replace">
        <![CDATA[public function oldftp() {]]>
      </add>
    </operation>
```

to:

```
<operation>
    <search position="replace"> 
     <![CDATA[ public function ftp() { ]]>
         </search>
        <add> 
     <![CDATA[ public function oldftp() { ]]>
       </add>
    </operation>
```

The position attribute now in search tag. I did it for both of the operation tag.
and I've changed this line:

```
$directory = DIR_UPLOAD . str_replace(array('../', '..\', '..'), '', $this->request->post['path']) . '/upload/';
```

to:

```
$directory = DIR_DOWNLOAD . str_replace(array('../', '..\', '..'), '', $this->request->post['path']) . '/upload/';
```

it works properly in my sistem now.

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is available on the Opencart community,

I had the same problem and this was the fix I used.

Follow the instruction below:

1. Download the OCMOD modification file here: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/download&extension_download_id=805024
2. Unzip the file
3. Go to your OpenCart Admin Panel > Extensions > Extension Installer.
4. Click the Upload button and select the .xml file that you previously unzipped.

You should get a green message saying: "Success: You have installed your extension!”.

5. Now navigate to Extensions > Modifications and click on the Refresh button at the top right corner of the screen.

That should fix it for you

Ream more here: http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18892